# surface area of two connected surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

[image]

If you want to compute the surface area bounded by the upper hemisphere and the paraboloid, do you have to split the integral into two different surface integrals ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Math.SE. What is precisely the problem you are dealing with? I mean: do you want a suggestion on how to proceed for the calculation of the integral shown in the picture attached to your post? Anyway, be careful when you pose a question, and always provide context in order to help other users help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as the upper and bottom surfaces have different equations, they have different parametrizations, and therefore the integrals to compute the surface areas have different domains.